# Photoresistor Transistor Circuit

Tags: led, transistors, photoresistor

I am teaching myself electronics. I designed this circuit to use a photoresistor to trigger a transistor when I hit the photoresistor with a laser pointer. On the Arduino side, I want it to look like a push button. That worked so I wanted to add an led as visual feed back that the laser is hitting the target.

The only way I could figure how to do this was to add a 2nd transistor. It works, but is this the correct way? I don't want to use another pin on the Arduino.

In the pic, pin 11 is supplying the 5V and pin 8 is reading the port.

[image]

Comment: Please, use an actual schematic--this thing is very difficult to read.

Comment: @Felthry Ok. I've created a schematic. (Hopefully it's the same - as a beginner I am more comfortable with the breadboard graphics.) The lines in blue are what I am adding.

Comment: Oh my not only is the circuit is a mess, but you need to learn the basics of transistor amplification. The current through the collector and emitter is roughly equal to the current through the base and emitter times a certain amplification factor. If you put the load ie a LED on the emitter side of the transistor, then It pretty much loses the point of the transistor.

Comment: Also can't you just simply hook up the LED with resistor to another arduino pin?

Comment: @Bradman175 From what I understand there are 2 ways to use a transistor: amplifier or switch. I am trying to use switch mode for both these transistors. When there is no light on the photoresistor, there will be no current at the base (or very little). Then when the light hits it, the transistor switches on. Is that not correct?

Comment: Also, I don't want to use another pin because I want this part to be interchangeable with a different part that uses the same number of pins.

Comment: @Bradman175  you said "you need to learn the basics of transistor amplification"  The OP said, "I am teaching myself electronics."  So cut the kid some slack, we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: @Misunderstood I'm sorry if I meant it in a harsh way, because it's not my intention. My point was that it's best to learn the theory of transistor amplification before using one, unless you're following a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this circuit, the centre voltage divider is creating a voltage between 5 to almost 0, where the amount of light shown on the photoresistor determines this. This voltage changes the amount of current going through the transistors, which switches them on or off. The LED will turn on when light is shown but it will also set the arduino pin to low, which is inverted to whether light is shown or not. So you may need to change your program a bit. You can omit that 10k resistor if you set your pinmode to INPUT_PULLUP. This circuits only uses one IO pin which is that unconnected node on the right.
[image]
Although I rather prefer MOSFETs, you don't need to use them.

Comment: Finally got around to building this circuit. Works well. Thanks.

Comment: Also a bit of trivia here, it's possible that if you shine a specific amount of light on the LDR, you could make the LED shine without turning the IO pin to low (or the other way around). But since you're using a laser to turn it on and off, it doesn't matter here (assuming you don't intend to gradually change the brightness of it but rather like you said, a switch). Also next time, consider a phototransistor rather than a photoresistor. They are better and connects like a transistor but the base is controlled by light.